# Click button do not take action

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

```
test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  const [page0] = await Promise.all([
   page.goto('https://*********'),
   page.locator('#popUpCookies').click(),
   page.getByRole('button',{name:'ACEPTAR'}).click(),
  ]);
```

I was trying to make an automation step in order to click (accept) over a button in a pop-up for cookies. But this action "page.getByRole('button',{name:'ACEPTAR'}).click()", just put the cursor over the button do not click over the element. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the site, but maybe try running these 3 promises in series rather than in parallel, otherwise it's nondeterministic which click might happen first. `Promise.all()` runs everything at the same time, not one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As they are dependent steps/actions , they need to be executed sequentially not in parallel. Please try the below code:

```
 test('test', async ({ page }) => {
   await page.goto('https://*********')
   await page.locator('#popUpCookies').click()
   await page.getByRole('button',{name:'ACEPTAR'}).click()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!!. Still having same issue, even after apply your changes suggested, I don't now if this is because the the button that I'm trying to click it is whitin a different frame than the home.

Answer (score 0):

solved! like the button was inside a div I wrote this before to call the button:

await page.locator('//div[@id="cookies_options"]').click()